# How can i list the directory files in python?

Tags: python

I am not getting the output in order while i am sorting the list of files in directory

```py
import os
arr = sorted(os.listdir(r'D:\\Krish\\syn\\Python\\Washington'))
print(arr)
```

below is the output:

```
['1.pdf', '10.pdf', '11.pdf', '12.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf', '5.pdf', '6.pdf', '7.pdf', '8.pdf', '9.pdf']
```

Comment: It _is_ sorted... only in lexicographic order, same as you would get in Windows Explorer. If you want the 10 to go after the 9 you would have to rename your files as '01.pdf', '02.pdf' and so on (or to specify a `key` to `sorted` to change the sorting criteria)

Comment: Answers have been given that explain how you could do this for the data you've shown. However, for a truly robust approach, you need to think about the possibility that files may exist in the directory that do not begin with numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how strings are sorted. I understand what you want to do, and that can be done with a custom comparator.

```
def compare(item1, item2):
    return int(item1.split(".")[0]) - int(item2.split(".")[0])

arr = ['1.pdf', '10.pdf', '11.pdf', '12.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf', '5.pdf', '6.pdf', '7.pdf', '8.pdf', '9.pdf']

from functools import cmp_to_key
sorted_arr = sorted(arr, key=cmp_to_key(compare))
print(sorted_arr)
```

This gives:

```
['1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf', '5.pdf', '6.pdf', '7.pdf', '8.pdf', '9.pdf', '10.pdf', '11.pdf', '12.pdf']
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to sort as integer. it works

```
sorted(arr, key=lambda filename: int(filename.split('.')[0]))
```

the output is:

```
['1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf', '5.pdf', '6.pdf', '7.pdf', '8.pdf', '9.pdf', '10.pdf', '11.pdf', '12.pdf']
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, because the file names are strings, the list is sorted lexicographic.

You can try this:

```py
arr = sorted(os.listdir(r'D:\Krish\syn\Python\Washington'), key=lambda f: int(f[:f.index('.')]))
```

The `key` argument is the function that the `sorted` function uses to determine the order.

In the code above, the function I pass takes all the characters until the period and converts them to an integer.

So `"10.pdf"` will be converted to `10` (as an integer)